# How do I specify which version of UTF-8 I want (in Java)?

Tags: java, encoding

Due to some awkward legacy code, I need to pass some non-English text around as ansi/ascii strings that are visibly UTF-8 encoded. For the most part, this is working alright (I'm using URLEncoder). However, now I need it to be able to output different versions of UTF-8 in different circumstances, and I don't know how to do that.

For example, this character can be UTF-8 encoded these ways:

```
大
%u5927
&#22823;
%E5%A4%A7
```

But nothing seems to talk about the different versions, as though there is no difference. I know URLEncoder does not do the second version, because the & is a reserved character, but the second one is what I need in some instances. How can I convert the text to the specific version I want?

Specifically, it's being passed to a .jsp that contains a library called displaytag that handles the data and displays a table without much developer input, but it doesn't seem to have any options for setting the encoding. I know the second encoding (passed as ansi/ascii) in the above list is displays correctly without changing the .jsp, though, which is the safest option for me. I just need to get it that way.

Comment: `&#22823;` is the HTML entity encoding, not URL encoding!

Comment: As is `%u5927`. And `%E5%A4%A7` is URL encodin of a UTF8 string, not UTF8 itself.

Comment: @Gabe and @duskwuff, I do know that, and I realise that true UTF-8 encoding is all in memory, not really displayable like this, but this question is awkward to ask as I don't know all the terminology around it. Also, it's not really the point of my question. Or are you saying that HTML entity encoding is not the same as UTF-8 encoding? Either way, that gives me another phrase to Google search for. If I'm still confused after that, I'll come back and rephrase my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is the unicode code point in hex and is URL encoded, second is same in decimal and is the HTML/XML entity form.

Never used it for your purpose but I think [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) escapeHtml or escapeXml should give you the second form.

BTW the second form also has a hex version: `&#x5927;`

Third looks like a conversion by a non utf-8 aware function which has converted the three bytes that in utf-8 make up the single code point separately. The third is in my view incorrect because you cannot see if it are three ascii bytes or that it is in fact utf-8.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's exactly what I need. I understand it's probably a weird usage, and if it was my own project I wouldn't handle it like this at all. By the way, that third version is, in fact, the output from URLEncoder. Useful for when you need it to pass through a URL. Interestingly, Chrome even displays it as the character it is supposed to represent, but only when it's a variable after an "=" or something.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from the question, all you really want to ultimately do is display text.

You already understand that what is stored in memory or in files is byte sequences, pure and simple, and somehow you have the three-byte sequence e5 a4 a7, because that is the way the character OOKII HAJIME OOINI (大) is encoded in UTF-8.

To put this character in a URL using Java then yes you use URLEncoder and you will get %E5%A4%A7.  But if you want to display it on a JSP, then I would certain recommend the HTML entity `&#x5927;` because you won't be subject to end users setting up their browser's character encoding to mess with your byte stream if you decide to send the raw UTF-8 bytes.

How you do this depends on whether your data is stored as a byte array or a real Java string.  Generally, to output HTML numeric entities, you can do this programmatically by turning each character with codepoint above 7F into characters of the form

```
& # x codepoint ;
```

or search the web for a library that does that for you.  It is probably more work if you are processing a byte array, but it can be done. Commons Lang's StringEscapeUtils handles known named entities, but I do not believe it will create numeric HTML entities for characters with large codepoints.

Comment: Ah, "codepoint" is a term that's good to learn, thanks. StringEscapeUtils does do what I want. Presumably, it detects whether it can be named or not. Also, it's interesting to note that if you don't put `&#22823;` inside a code block, it gets displayed as the character as is what I think happened in your answer in the third paragraph.

Comment: Hey nice catch on the typo in the third paragraph :-)  Glad StringEscapeUtils works for you!

Comment: Fixed the third paragraph in my answer.